# make a process layer with android that work all the time

Tags: android, process, widget, background-process, layer

I have an idea of something I want to make on android 
but I'am not Java developer , but I can learn that shortly

what I want to ask is , **How I can make a layer in android that work all the time even when running other apps ?**

**I want to make background process that running all the time**

for example , imagine that I want to make a button that will take a screen shot and this button exist on the screen all the time even in apps

how I could do that in Android ?

and thanks

Comment: "I want to make a button that will take a screen shot" -- that is not possible, except on rooted devices, for obvious privacy and security reasons.

Comment: ok , how to do that with rooted devices ?